# Why does loop unrolling have no effect for a large dataset?

Tags: c++, optimization, loop-unrolling

I wanted to benchmark the difference in execution speed between an unrolled loop and a for loop applied on a `triangle` object. The entire example is available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4a8e7800962a285).

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>

template<typename RT>
class Point 
{
    std::array<RT,3> data; 

    public: 

        Point() = default;

        Point(std::initializer_list<RT>& ilist)
            :
                data(ilist)
        {}

        Point(RT x, RT y, RT z)
            :
                data({x,y,z})
        {};

        RT& operator[](int i)
        {
            return data[i];  
        }

        RT operator[](int i) const
        {
            return data[i];
        }

        const Point& operator += (Point const& other)
        {
            data[0] += other.data[0];
            data[1] += other.data[1];
            data[2] += other.data[2];

            return *this; 
        }

        const Point& operator /= (RT const& s)
        {
            data[0] /= s; 
            data[1] /= s;  
            data[2] /= s;  

            return *this;
        }

};

template<typename RT>
Point<RT> operator-(const Point<RT>& p1, const Point<RT>& p2)
{
    return Point<RT>(p1[0] - p2[0], p1[1] - p2[1], p1[2] - p2[2]);
}

template<typename RT>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os , Point<RT> const& p)
{
    os << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2]; 
    return os;
}

template<typename Point>
class Triangle 
{
    std::array<Point, 3> points; 

    public: 

        typedef typename std::array<Point, 3>::value_type value_type;

        typedef Point PointType; 

        Triangle() = default; 

        Triangle(std::initializer_list<Point>& ilist) 
            :
                points(ilist)
        {}

        Triangle(Point const& p1, Point const& p2, Point const& p3)
            :
                points({p1, p2, p3})
        {}

        Point& operator[](int i)
        {
            return points[i]; 
        }

        Point operator[](int i) const
        {
            return points[i]; 
        }

        auto begin()
        {
            return points.begin(); 
        }

        const auto begin() const
        {
            return points.begin(); 
        }

        auto end()
        {
            return points.end(); 
        }

        const auto end() const
        {
            return points.end(); 
        }
};

template<typename Triangle>
typename Triangle::PointType barycenter_for(Triangle const& triangle)
{
    typename Triangle::value_type barycenter; 

    for (const auto& point : triangle)
    {
        barycenter += point; 
    }

    barycenter /= 3.; 

    return barycenter; 
}

template<typename Triangle>
typename Triangle::PointType barycenter_unrolled(Triangle const& triangle)
{
    typename Triangle::PointType barycenter; 

    barycenter += triangle[0]; 
    barycenter += triangle[1]; 
    barycenter += triangle[2]; 

    barycenter /= 3.; 

    return barycenter; 
}

template<typename TriangleSequence>
typename TriangleSequence::value_type::value_type
barycenter(
    TriangleSequence const& triangles, 
    std::function
    <
        typename TriangleSequence::value_type::value_type (
            typename TriangleSequence::value_type const &
         )
    > triangle_barycenter 
)
{
    typename TriangleSequence::value_type::value_type barycenter; 

    for(const auto& triangle : triangles)
    {
        barycenter += triangle_barycenter(triangle); 
    }

    barycenter /= double(triangles.size()); 

    return barycenter; 
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    typedef Point<double> point; 
    typedef Triangle<point> triangle; 

    const int EXP = (atoi(argv[1]));

    ofstream outFile; 
    outFile.open("results.dat",std::ios_base::app); 

    const unsigned int MAX_TRIANGLES = pow(10, EXP);

    typedef std::vector<triangle> triangleVector; 

    triangleVector triangles;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10,10); 

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_TRIANGLES; ++i)
    {
        triangles.push_back(
            triangle(
                point(dist(e), dist(e), dist(e)),
                point(dist(e), dist(e), dist(e)),
                point(dist(e), dist(e), dist(e))
            )
        );
    }

    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock; 

    auto start = Clock::now();
    auto trianglesBarycenter = barycenter(triangles, [](const triangle& tri){return barycenter_for(tri);});
    auto end = Clock::now(); 

    auto forLoop = end - start; 

    start = Clock::now();
    auto trianglesBarycenterUnrolled = barycenter(triangles, [](const triangle& tri){return barycenter_unrolled(tri);});
    end = Clock::now(); 

    auto unrolledLoop = end - start; 

    cout << "Barycenter difference (should be a zero vector): " << trianglesBarycenter - trianglesBarycenterUnrolled << endl;

    outFile << MAX_TRIANGLES << " " << forLoop.count() << " " << unrolledLoop.count() << "\n"; 

    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The example consists of a Point type, and a Triangle type. The benchmarked calculation is the calculation of the triangle barycenter. It can be done with a for loop:

```
for (const auto& point : triangle)
{
    barycenter += point; 
}

barycenter /= 3.; 

return barycenter;
```

or it can be unrolled since a triangle has three points:

```
barycenter += triangle[0]; 
barycenter += triangle[1]; 
barycenter += triangle[2]; 

barycenter /= 3.; 

return barycenter;
```

So I wanted to test which function that computes a barycenter will be faster, for a set of triangles. To make the most of the test, I made the number of triangles being operated on variable by executing the main program with an integer exponent argument:

```
./main 6
```

resulting in 10^6 triangles. The number of triangles is ranging from 100 to 1e06. The main program creates "results.dat" file. To analyze the results, I've coded a small python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

results = np.loadtxt("results.dat")

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.loglog(); 
ax2.loglog();

ratio = results[:,1] / results[:,2]

print("Speedup factors unrolled loop / for loop: ")
print(ratio)

l1 = ax1.plot(results[:,0], results[:,1], label="for loop", color='red')
l2 = ax1.plot(results[:,0], results[:,2], label="unrolled loop", color='black')
l3 = ax2.plot(results[:,0], ratio, label="speedup ratio", color='green')

lines  = [l1, l2, l3]; 

ax1.set_ylabel("CPU count")
ax2.set_ylabel("relative speedup: unrolled loop / for loop")

ax1.legend(loc="center right")
ax2.legend(loc="center left")

plt.savefig("results.png")
```

And to make use of all that on your computer, copy the example code, compile it with:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -o main
```

To plot the measured CPU time for different barycenter functions, execute the python script (I've called it `plotResults.py`):

```
 for i in {1..6}; do ./main $i; done
./plotResults.py
```

What I have expected to see is that the relative speedup between the unrolled loop and the `for` loop (for loop time / unrolled loop time) will increase with the size of the triangle set. This conclusion would follow from a logic: if an unrolled loop is faster than a for loop, executing a lot of unrolled loops should be faster than executing a lot of for loops. Here is a diagram of the results that is generated by the above python script:

[image]

The impact of loop unrolling dies of fast. As soon as I am working with more than 100 triangles, there seems to be no difference. Looking at the speedup computed by the python script:

```
[ 3.13502399  2.40828402  1.15045831  1.0197221   1.1042312   1.26175165
  0.99736715]
```

the speedup when 100 triangles are used (3d place in the list corresponds to 10^2) is 1.15.

I came here to find out what I did wrong, because there must be something wrong here, IMHO. :) Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: plotting cachegrind cache miss ratios

If the program is run like this:

```
for input in {2..6}; do valgrind --tool=cachegrind  ./main $input; done
```

`cachegrind` generates a bunch of output files, that can be parsed with `grep` for `PROGRAM TOTALS`, a list of numbers representing the following data, taken from the [cachegrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html):

> Cachegrind gathers the following statistics (abbreviations used for
>   each statistic is given in parentheses):
>
> ```
> I cache reads (Ir, which equals the number of instructions executed), I1 cache read misses (I1mr) and LL cache instruction read
> ```
>
> misses (ILmr).
>
> ```
> D cache reads (Dr, which equals the number of memory reads), D1 cache read misses (D1mr), and LL cache data read misses (DLmr).
>
> D cache writes (Dw, which equals the number of memory writes), D1 cache write misses (D1mw), and LL cache data write misses (DLmw).
>
> Conditional branches executed (Bc) and conditional branches mispredicted (Bcm).
>
> Indirect branches executed (Bi) and indirect branches mispredicted (Bim).
> ```

And the "combined" cache miss ratio is defined as: (ILmr + DLmr + DLmw) / (Ir + Dr + Dw)

The output files can be parsed like this:

```
for file in cache*; do cg_annotate $file | grep TOTALS >> program-totals.dat; done
sed -i 's/PROGRAM TOTALS//'g program-totals.dat
```

and the resulting data can be then visualized using this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import locale

totalInput = [totalInput.strip().split(' ') for totalInput in open('program-totals.dat','r')]

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 

totals = []

for line in totalInput:
    totals.append([locale.atoi(item) for item in line])

totals = np.array(totals)

# Assumed default output format
# Ir I1mr  ILmr Dr Dmr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
# 0   1     2   3   4   5   6   7    8
cacheMissRatios = (totals[:,2] + totals[:,5] + totals[:,8]) / (totals[:,0] + totals[:,3] + totals[:,6])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.loglog()

results = np.loadtxt("results.dat")
l1 = ax1.plot(results[:,0], cacheMissRatios, label="Cachegrind combined cache miss ratio", color='black', marker='x')
l1 = ax1.plot(results[:,0], results[:,1] / results[:,2], label="Execution speedup", color='blue', marker='o')

ax1.set_ylabel("Cachegrind combined cache miss ratio")
ax1.set_xlabel("Number of triangles")
ax1.legend(loc="center left")

plt.savefig("cacheMisses.png")
```

So, ploting the combined LL miss rate against the program speedup when the triangle access loop is unrolled, results in the following diagram:

[image]

And there seems to be a dependence in the LL mis rate : as it goes up, the speedup of the program goes down. But still, I can't see a clear reason for the bottleneck.

Is the combined LL miss rate the right thing to analyze? Looking at the valgrind output, all miss rates are reported to be less than 5%, this should be quite OK, right?

Comment: Depending where you run the code, timing is only accurate for 15ms aka an eternity. Check the code, but the compiler should be more than capable of doing that optimization itself.

Comment: If the compiler does the optimization itself, why is there a large difference in the execution time for small sets of triangles? I would expect the loop unrolling to be performed for a small set of triangles, not for 1e06 triangles...

Comment: Can you please post your complete c code? It is hard to know how you are testing from your description alone. For instance how you measure the time.

Comment: You also forgot to pass `-DNDEBUG`. Might affect the iterator speed.

Comment: @Cameron : passed `-DNDEBUG`, there is no significant difference.

Comment: Maybe relative to branch prediction ?

Comment: @Jarod Branch prediction in a code without any branches apart from completely predictable loops (which in this case even an ancient pentium would get right, because those just assumed the backwards branch is taken)

Comment: I've taken a moment to look carefully at the code. My intuition says that as the vector sizes increase, the cost of fetching non-cache data overwhelms the relatively minor cost of loop counting. For very small data sets, where there are few cache misses in comparison to counted loops, I would expect to see a small performance improvement.

Comment: @Richard a cache line is 64 byte so only three triangles fit into one line. Wouldn't the loop count be linear to the number of cache misses independent of size?

Comment: O.K. as I see full source I remove my previous comment, because you only unrolled triangle loop (I thought you unrolled this giant triangles loop along with it). Still IMO this behavior has something to do with cache and like Richard said for large data fetching it from main memory may be a major impact on performance.

Comment: `"if an unrolled loop is faster than a for loop, executing a lot of unrolled loops should be faster than executing a lot of for loops"` - try to do it N-th times for one triangle (although you may modify its points to prevent some compiler optimizations).

Comment: BTW you should run second test with same preconditions as first one. Make another program instead of running tests one after another. For example when you pass `triangles` to your `barycenter` function second time, reference is already initialized, because you used it in the first test and compiler may take advantage of it making second call a bit faster.

Comment: @Voo I don't think compiler is able to unroll iterator based loop as it can do with counted loops.

Comment: @doc: I have used another program and initialized the exponent from argv[1]. I'm checking cache misses in the LL cache with valgrind, to see if there is an issue there. As expected, the cache miss ratio goes to 0% with large datasets - it's a huge vector.

Comment: @tmaric :o cache miss or cache hit?

Comment: @doc, the LL miss rate drops to zero: (ILmr + DLmr + DLmw) / (Ir + Dr + Dw) [from the cachegdind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html)

Comment: @tmaric ah OK, LL is a last level cache = main memory.

Answer (score 4):

Even with your unrolling, calculation of  `barycenter` is done one at a time. Furthermore, each step of the calculation (for a single barycenter) depends on the previous one, which means that they cannot be parallelized. You could certainly achieve a better throughput by computing `n` barycenters at once, instead of just one, and benchmark on various values for `n` to determine which amount will saturate the CPU pipelines.

Another aspect which might help speeding up the computation is the *data layout*: instead of storing triangle points together in a single struct, you could try splitting them in 3 different arrays (one for each point), and again benchmark with different values for `n`.

Regarding your main question, unless the code transformation reduces the degree of complexity of the underlying algorithm (which is totally possible), the gained speed should be at most linear on the data set size, but with a sufficiently large one, it is likely to hit different limits (for instance, what happens when one level of memory - cache level 1, level 2, main memory - becomes saturated?).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out your suggestions. About the second paragraph: I think I can't transform the data layout for the triangles, because other algorithms depend on them being packed together. Using indirect addressing introduces more complexity for the algorithms that operate on triangle collections.

Comment: Indeed, the second transformation is a bit more ambitious. Btw, it's nice to see a question with that well written C++ code, thank you for asking it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help + the positive comment on the C++ code. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your second BarycenterUnrolled loop is faster for small datasets because the dataset is small enough to be L2/L3 cache-optimized.  Try swapping the order in which you run the tests within your program.  A seemingly logical decision might be to run the tests as separate processes, but that doesn't always work either: the L2/L3 caches are persistent.  Subsequent runs of each process can yield different results.  (see below for more details)
2. The rest of the differences you observe along the spectrum are noise.  Your GCC compiler is generating nearly identical code in both cases.  GCC is well-known for aggressively unrolling loops such as that one, when -O3 is specified.  In fact, GCC will unroll loops up to 16 or 24 iterations in some cases -- which is sometimes to the detriment of performance on some mobile chip architectures.

Also, you can test with -fno-unroll-loops ... though I doubt you'll see much diff since the main bottlenecks of your algo are, in this order:

1. The Division operation  (/= 3)
2. Memory

Regarding running proper benchmark tests on short data sets:

In order to avoid L2/L3 cache noise on short datasets, you'll need to flush the caches prior to each benchmark test.  This is normally done by allocating some large chunk of data in the heap of ~16MB - 32MB and reading/writing garbage to it.  In your case here, building completely different triangle lists for each test is also advisable.

But the best advice is usually: "don't run benchmarks on small data sets."  Instead, run benchmarks only on very large data sets and then use the best also at large sets for small sets.  This works well for micro-optimization cases, like loop unrolling or cpu instruction counting.  If you're doing higher-level algos like sorting or tree-walking and know that your primary usage cases will be small data sets, then a different set of benchmark criteria should be used.  In those cases I prefer to create a "large" data set by concatenating dozens of small data sets.  That'll stress the portions of the algo that might be a bottleneck for small datasets, such as setup and result processing.

Answer (score 0):

Loop unrolling saves you the overhead of a loop. If the time it takes to do the looping is small to the time to execute each single iteration of the loop then you aren't going to save much.

It can be worse. Your processor has many units working kind of independently. For example, you might have a memory unit, a floating-point unit, and an integer unit. Your code will take as long as the slowest of these units take. The loop (incrementing the index, checking that it is small enough, starting at the beginning of the loop) is performed by the integer unit. If you have code that would take 100ms in the memory unit, 80ms in the floating point unit, and 60ms in the integer unit, then it takes 100ms. Any savings in the floating point or integer unit don't make it faster at all.

Note that with small examples all the data fits into caches. So the memory unit would take relatively less time. Let's say you have a small sample that without unrolling takes 60µs (memory), 60µs (floating point) and 80µs (integer). Now loop unrolling can help and reduce the total time from 80µs to 60µs.